# how to use smsserver.java from smslib? I have read the docs

Tags: java, mysql, smslib

I am triying to save my sms to a mysql database, I added the conector mysql jar to netbeans, and I added the smsserver.java and conf files, also I created a mysql database called sms but when I run the smsserver.java just print this:

```
SMSLib: A Java API library for sending and receiving SMS via a GSM modem or other supported gateways.
This software is distributed under the terms of the Apache v2.0 License.
Web Site: http://smslib.org

SMSLib API version: 3.5.1
SMSServer version: 3.5.1
```

how It can I make to work this file? I dont understand and  I have read the docs but I still dont get it, can someone help me?? indeed I send messages and I can read messages, but with this I have troubles

My structure of files is like this:

[image]

help very apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Have you tried sending or receiving any SMS messages?

Q: Have you looked at the SMSLib Wiki?

http://code.google.com/p/smslib/wiki/Documentation_Index?tm=6

Comment: 1-With this lib I have send sms and I can read sms and 2- The wiki says almost the same as the official page, but I will have to read another time because I can get it to work the smsserver.java file